# Is there a sequence of real numbers such that the set of its subsequential limits is $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Is there a sequence of real numbers such that the set of its subsequential limits is $[0,1]$?

I've been considering the sequence:
$$1,~~\frac12,~~\frac22,~~\frac32,~~\frac13,~~\frac23,~~\frac33,~~\frac43,~\ldots~,~~\frac1n,~~\frac2n,~~\frac3n,~\ldots~,~~\frac{n+1}{n},~\ldots$$

Does it satisfy the condition?

Comment: Observe: any sequence is a countable set, but the real numbers on $[0,1]$ are uncountable.

Comment: @janmarqz That's not actually relevant to this problem.

Comment: I think that might actually work... this is an extremely interesting question. I am pretty sure this sequence will contain every rational number between 0 and 1, and for every irrational there is a sequence of rationals converging to it, so I can't see why not. I also think the 3/2, 4/3, 5/3 terms might be unnecessary, is there a particular reason you included them?

Comment: @janmarqz but the number of subsequences is uncountable.

Comment: i'm not telling lies but displaying some truth

Comment: @janmarqz I never said you were incorrect - I just said your observation was irrelevant to this specific problem.

Comment: You can slightly 'simplify' your sequence by dropping the $(n+1)/n$ terms. It's not important, but perhaps a bit niceer to have all the terms be in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Why does this question have a close vote? It is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It provides little context (he does not tell what was his trouble on proving that the sequence works), he asks two different questions in title/body, he did not use TeX (which was edited away)... although the question itself is appropriate, I think the way it was displayed by OP may have been somewhat lacking. (By the way, it was not me who vote to close.)

Comment: @mathers101 I included 3/2, 4/3, 5/4... in order to achieve a subsequence which converges to 1

Comment: Isn't the subsequence 1, $2\over2$, $3\over3$, ... already converge to 1? In general every rational $p\over q$ has a subsequence $p\over q$, $2p\over 2q$, ... which converge to it.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo yep, exactly what cr001. It's taken care of by $1, 2/2,3/3,4/4,\dots$

Comment: @cr001 you are right!

Answer (score 5):

That does indeed work.

Another option is to let $a_n=\vert\sin(n)\vert$ - this is a good exercise.

Or, we can pick an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1]$.

Comment: Beat me by literally 4 seconds : P.

Answer (score 2):

For the question of the title: Consider $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$.

For the question of the body: Yes. For any $x \in [0,1]$ you can construct a subsequence as follows: Pick the first element as $1$. Now, given the $i$-th element constructed, for the next consider the $\frac{1}{i+1}$-neighbourhood, pick a number with denominator greater than the last one and slide the numerator until it reaches the neighbourhood (you can guarantee that this is possible by picking a large enough denominator by the Archimedean property).

Comment: Nice and simple, I like it.

Comment: The question was: "does it satisfy the condition?" where "it" is the sequence defined by the OP.

Comment: What's relevant is not just the limit points of the set.  It's the limits of subsequences.  So this answer is incomplete without some order to the sequence.

Comment: @GEdgar Although I believe the error is more on behalf of OP than on me by asking two different questions, I "fixed" the answer.

Comment: @Paul It is essentially a hint (which is implied by "consider"). It answers the question after proper thinking, and is part of the design of the answer. Just like my outline to the other question.

Comment: @GEdgar the title asks "is there a sequence", which I believe Aloizio provided