# Determine if Cantor Set represents a set of subsequential limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

How does one show whether the Cantor set represents the set of subsequential limits of some real number sequence? I.E. Does there exist a real number sequence with that as the set of its subsequential limits?

The only resource I can find for this problem is a similar question for real number intervals ([Is there a sequence of real numbers such that the set of its subsequential limits is $[0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502824/is-there-a-sequence-of-real-numbers-such-that-the-set-of-its-subsequential-limit)). I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of subsequential limits of some sequence of real numbers.

Hint: Find a countable dense subset.

Solution:

Let $F$ be a nonempty closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Define

$$\Omega = \{ B(q; r) \cap F \neq \emptyset | q, r \in \mathbb{Q}, r > 0 \}=\{ B_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$$

Note that $\Omega$ is a countable basis for the topology of $F$(the one induced from $\mathbb{R}$).

For each $n \ge 1$, take $x_n \in B_n$.

Given an $x \in F$ and an open(in $F$) neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, since $\Omega$ is a basis, there is some $n_0$ such that $x_{n_0} \in B_{n_0} \subset U$.

Therefore, each point in $F$ is a subsequential limit of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Furthermore, since $F$ is closed and $x_n \in F$, every subsequential limit of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ belong to $F$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide justification or a reference as to why every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of sub sequential limits of some sequence of real numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The Cantor set $C$ is represented as the intersection of a sequence of subsets $$C_0 \supset C_1 \supset C_2 \supset C_3 \supset...
$$ 
which is defined inductively by setting $C_0=[0,1]$, and defining $C_{i+1}$ by removing the open middle third of each component of $C_i$, so for example 
$$C_1 = [0,1/3] \cup [2/3,1/3]
$$
$$C_2 = [0/9,1/9] \cup [2/9,3/9] \cup [6/9,7/9] \cup [8/9,9/9]
$$
The key idea is that $\mathbb R - C$ is a union of countably many open intervals, namely the two half-infinite intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(1,\infty)$, together with all the open intervals that are deleted at each stage of the induction, deleted from $C_i$ to form $C_{i+1}$. Each endpoint of one of those deleted open intervals remains in $C$, and that set of endpoints is a countable dense subset of $C$. If you can enumerate those endpoints, you'll have your sequence.

I'll describe an enumeration similar to the one in the linked question. The first idea key is to use only those denominators which are powers of $3$. The second is that when enumerating the fractions with denominator $3^i$, the only new endpoints added are the endpoints of the open intervals of $C_{i-1}$ that are deleted to form $C_i$; so you have to skip over some of the fractions with denomiantor $3^i$.

The two endpoints of interval $C_0=[0,1]$ are $0$ and $1$ which are the start of the sequence:
$$0,1
$$
The four endpoints of two-interval set $C_1$ are the next four terms of the sequence, written with denominator $3$:
$$0/3,1/3,2/3,3/3
$$
The eight endpoints of the four-intervals set $C_2$ are the next eight terms of the sequence, written with denominator $9$:
$$0/9,1/9,2/9,3/9,6/9,7/9,8/9,9/9
$$
So far we therefore have
$$0,1,\frac{0}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{3}, \frac{0}{9}, \frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9},\frac{3}{9}, \frac{6}{9},\frac{7}{9},\frac{8}{9},\frac{9}{9},...
$$
the sixteen endpoints of the eight-interval set $C_3$ are the next sixteen terms, written with denominator $27$, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

If a metric space $X$ has a countable dense subset, then so does any subset of $X$ (in the same metric). Because $\mathbb R$ has a countable dense subset, it follows that the Cantor set $C$ does too. Let $\{d_1,d_2,\dots \}$ be a countable dense subset of $C.$ Then every element of $C$ is the limit of a subsequence of

$$d_1,d_1,d_2, d_1,d_2,d_3,d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,\dots $$

And because $C$ is closed, any limit of a sequence in $C$ belongs to $C.$